# How to create a reused variable in flutter,which needs to be initialized?

Tags: flutter, global-variables

Following the example code

```
void main() async {
  CloudBaseCore core = CloudBaseCore.init({'env': 'your-env-id'});

  CloudBaseDatabase db = CloudBaseDatabase(core);

  Collection collection = db.collection('user');
}
```

I want to use this variable `collection` in different files, so how can I define it?

I tried to define it as a class member,but it warned that initialization is must.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just maintain all the properties in a helper class and initialize all the properties inside the constructor and use them into the different classes by passing it as a parameter,

```
void main() async {
  DataBaseHelper helper = DataBaseHelper();

  // Now, you can use helper.collection to all your classes. 
  helper.collection;
}

class DataBaseHelper {
  DataBaseHelper() {
    core = CloudBaseCore.init({'env': 'your-env-id'});
    db = CloudBaseDatabase(core);
    collection = db.collection('user');
  }

  late CloudBaseCore core;

  late CloudBaseDatabase db;

  late Collection collection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I add ? to avoid null check, but I dont know whether it's a good solution.